# json generated with rabl includes a wrapped_string attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, rabl

My model:

```
def full_name
  "#{first_name} #{middle_name} #{last_name} #{suffix_name}".mb_chars.upcase.squeeze(' ').strip
end
```

My rabl template:

```
collection @users
attributes :id, :full_name
```

This is inserting an extra child named `wrapped_string`

```
[{"user":{"id":73,"full_name":{"wrapped_string":"FOO BAR"}}}]
```

but I need something like:

```
[{"user":{"id":73,"full_name":"FOO BAR"}}]
```

If I don't use `mb_chars` works great, but I must to use it. What should I do?

Comment: Sounds stupid but have you tried to add `to_s` after the strip?

Comment: @MrYoshiji Haha, it was stupid. Thanks for the tip ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `to_s` to convert the MultiByte::Chars into a string again:

```
def full_name
  "#{first_name} #{middle_name} #{last_name} #{suffix_name}".mb_chars.upcase.squeeze(' ').strip.to_s
end
```